# How to edit datagrid row backcolor in c# .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a .NET  Compact Framework 2.0 smart device app.I use datagrid (not datagridView because .NET  Compact Framework smart device app not supportly).How can i change backcolor of row dynamically for run time?

```
my code here  

DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Jobs");
DataRow row= dt.NewRow();
row["Name"] = "aaaa";
row["Jobs"] = "bbbb";
dt.Rows.Add(row);

myDataGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: its not solve this link my problem

Answer (score 0):

its a bit complicated to change backcolor of the row of datagrid in CF.

Firstly there should be a ColumnStyle  class which inherits from DataGridTextBoxColumn where you will implement paint event of DataGridTextBoxColumn.

```
namespace SmartBox
{
    public delegate void CheckCellEventHandler(object sender, DataGridEnableEventArgs e);

    public class DataGridEnableEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private int _column;
        private int _row;
        private bool _meetsCriteria;

        public DataGridEnableEventArgs(int row, int col)//
        {
            _row = row;
            _column = col;
        }

        public DataGridEnableEventArgs(int row, int col, bool val)//
        {
            _row = row;
            _column = col;
            _meetsCriteria = val;
        }

        public int Column
        {
            get { return _column; }
            set { _column = value; }
        }

        public int Row
        {
            get { return _row; }
            set { _row = value; }
        }

        public bool MeetsCriteria
        {
            get { return _meetsCriteria; }
            set { _meetsCriteria = value; }
        }
    }


    class ColumnStyle : DataGridTextBoxColumn
    {
        public event CheckCellEventHandler CheckCellEven;
        public event CheckCellEventHandler CheckRowContains;

        private int _col;

        public ColumnStyle(int column)
        {
            _col = column;
        }

        protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle Bounds, CurrencyManager Source, int RowNum, Brush BackBrush, Brush ForeBrush, bool AlignToRight)
        {
            bool enabled = true;

            if (CheckCellEven != null)
            {
                DataGridEnableEventArgs e = new DataGridEnableEventArgs(RowNum,_col, enabled);//, _col
                CheckCellEven(this, e);
                if (e.MeetsCriteria)
                    BackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.PaleGreen);

            }

            if (CheckRowContains != null)
            {
                DataGridEnableEventArgs e = new DataGridEnableEventArgs(RowNum, _col, enabled);
                CheckRowContains(this, e);
                if (e.MeetsCriteria)
                {
                    BackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
                }
            }

            base.Paint(g, Bounds, Source, RowNum, BackBrush, ForeBrush, AlignToRight);
        }
    }
```

and at the main form , decide with what conditions you will paint the row backcolor.

```
private void addGridStyle(ref DataGrid dg, DataTable cem)
    {
        DataGridTableStyle dtStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        dtStyle.MappingName = cem.TableName;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ColumnStyle myStyle = new ColumnStyle(i);
            myStyle.MappingName = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;

            if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "urunadi" || dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "urunkodu" || dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "toplanan_miktar" || dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "miktar")
                myStyle.CheckCellEven += new CheckCellEventHandler(myStyle_isEven);

            if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "urunadi" || dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "urunkodu" || dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "toplanan_miktar" || dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "miktar")
                myStyle.CheckRowContains += new CheckCellEventHandler(myStyle_CheckRowContains);

            dtStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(myStyle);
        }
        dg.TableStyles.Add(dtStyle);
        dg.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
    }

    public void myStyle_isEven(object sender, DataGridEnableEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((int)toplamaGrid[e.Row, 2] == (int)toplamaGrid[e.Row, 3])
                e.MeetsCriteria = true;
            else
                e.MeetsCriteria = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            e.MeetsCriteria = false;
        }
    }

    public void myStyle_CheckRowContains(object sender, DataGridEnableEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (((int)toplamaGrid[e.Row, 2] > (int)toplamaGrid[e.Row, 3]) && (int)toplamaGrid[e.Row, 3] > 0)
                e.MeetsCriteria = true;
            else
                e.MeetsCriteria = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            e.MeetsCriteria = false;
        }
    }
```

To be clear I post the whole about the changing backcolor of the datagrid row.

I have 2 methods(myStyle_CheckRowContains,myStyle_isEven) to decide which color I will make row's background.(Yellow and green). In my datagrid I have 4 columns which come from sql to Datatable(dt). I check the rows 1 by 1 and if value of 3rd column and 4th column of the row is equal then I paint row background to yellow. If value of 3rd column is bigger than the 4th colunm then I paint the background to yellow.

I hope I helped. If there is something you can ask. This problem really take some of my valuable time. I changed and implemented what I've seen here: [datagrid formatting](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20268/NET-CF-Custom-DataGrid-Formatting)